# Conversion of single precision double into a floating point

Tags: numerical-methods

How do I convert $0$ $00000001$ $00000000000000000000000$ into a floating point number?

Apparently the sign is +

I've started with $00000001$ which is 1 in decimal.

Then I applied formula $exponent = c -127 \Rightarrow exponent = -126$
and I got stuck.

Comment: What do you mean "convert into a floating point number"? What form should the result have, $1.234\times 2^p$, $1.234\times 10^e$? Or what? (Also: hidden bit)

Comment: Yes, in that form

Comment: Which one? $2^p$ or $10^e$?

Comment: $10^e$, but if you show me how to find the second one as well, I would be very grateful .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is IEEE754 single precision.  In which case

The sign bit is 0 so the the number is positive

The exponent $e$ is $00000001_2 = 1$

The mantissa $m$ is $1.00000000000000000000000_2 = 1 $  The leading 1 is implied.

The number is thus

$m \times 2^{e-127} = 1 \times 2^{-126} \approx 1.17549435082228750796873653722 \times 10^{-38}$

There is an interactive tool [here](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html)

And more information on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: Small typo: The sign bit is 0.

Comment: @gammatester Thanks I've edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Hint: IEEE singles have a hidden implied highest bit in the mantissa. Therefore your number is the smallest normalised positive single (32-bit) number, and the answer is
$2^{-126} \approx 0.117549435\cdot10^{-37}$